# Loading effect using react hookss

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I am trying to add loading effect using React hook(useEffect) on my web page but i don't know why it's not work, have look..................

> this is the App componant......................

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import data from "./data";
import Loading from './Loading'
import SingleQuestion from "./Question";

function App() {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState(data);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const fetchData = async() => {
      const respons = await fetch(data)
      const newData = await respons.json();
      setQuestions(newData)
      setLoading(false)
  }
  useEffect(() =>{
    fetchData();
  },[]);

  if(loading){
    return(
      <main>
        <Loading />
      </main>
    )
  }
  return (
    <main>
      <div className="container">
        <h3>question and answers about login</h3>
        <section className="info">
          {questions.map((question) => {
            return (
              <SingleQuestion key={question.id} {...question}></SingleQuestion>
            );
          })}
        </section>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> data file..........

```
const questions = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Do I have to allow the use of cookies?',
      info:
        'Unicorn vinyl poutine brooklyn, next level direct trade iceland. Shaman copper mug church-key coloring book, whatever poutine normcore fixie cred kickstarter post-ironic street art.',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'How do I change my My Page password?',
      info:
        'Coloring book forage photo booth gentrify lumbersexual. Migas chillwave poutine synth shoreditch, enamel pin thundercats fashion axe roof party polaroid chartreuse.',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'What is BankID?',
      info:
        'Enamel pin fam sustainable woke whatever venmo. Authentic asymmetrical put a bird on it, lumbersexual activated charcoal kinfolk banjo cred pickled sartorial.',
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: 'Whose birth number can I use?',
      info:
        'Edison bulb direct trade gentrify beard lo-fi seitan sustainable roof party franzen occupy squid. Knausgaard cronut succulents, scenester readymade shabby chic lyft. Copper mug meh vegan gentrify.',
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      title: 'When do I recieve a password ordered by letter?',
      info:
        'Locavore franzen fashion axe live-edge neutra irony synth af tilde shabby chic man braid chillwave waistcoat copper mug messenger bag. Banjo snackwave blog, microdosing thundercats migas vaporware viral lo-fi seitan ',
    },
  ]
  export default questions
```

Showing error is like.............

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: use `map` function, there's no api calling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not making an api call, you don't need to use `fetch`. You can map the data right away.

Comment: hmm now I understand but what about loading effect how can i connect it! can you please define.....

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what's happening here. When you import some data locally, there is no loading time. The data is loaded into the component right away, and then rendered. If you want to set an artificial loading time, you use the ```setTimeout``` function. However the loading effect you tried to make will indeed work, if you make an API call to a server instead.